# How does React manage memory?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

## What I want to know

I am looking into memory management in React. First I looked into JavaScript's GC and learned that it uses two algorithms to free unneeded memory. Then I wanted to know how React performs memory management. [When I looked into it, I found only articles about setState and not about overall memory management.](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/82) I have never cared about memory management in React or Next.js, so I would like to know how it is managed. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: You do not manage memory in Javascript nor in any garbage collected language. The only thing to watch out for is "memory leaks" where a program keeps a reference by accident, so it's never freed by GC.

Comment: @AndyRayI agree that JavaScript automatically frees memory so we don't have to be aware of memory. What I want to know is why we don't need to be aware of memory leaks in React and how it works.

Comment: That wasn't your question, and it's the same as any Javascript program, as I described. Research "Javascript memory leak" for more.

Comment: I had never been aware of freeing memory after multiple functions in a component and accessing them, which I thought led to memory leaks in closures as in Javascrit, but since that was never a problem in React, I thought React was doing some magic.